# Adding to a column 10 options on PLSQL

Tags: oracle, ddl, check-constraints

I want to add column but it should be 10 options to my database(PL/SQL).

My sql query is look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD NEWCOL
```

Do you think that is it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have to *think*, I *know* it won't work.

```
SQL> INSERT_INTO MYTABLE
  2  (MYNEW_COL)
  3  VALUES
  4  (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
INSERT_INTO MYTABLE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

If you want to insert exactly those values, use a row generator:

```
SQL> insert into mytable (mynew_col)
  2  select level from dual
  3  connect by level <= 10;

10 rows created.

SQL> select * from mytable;

 MYNEW_COL
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6
         7
         8
         9
        10

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Otherwise, discover other valid ways to do that, such as

```
SQL> insert into mytable (mynew_col)
  2  select 1 from dual union all
  3  select 2 from dual union all
  4  select 3 from dual;

3 rows created.
```

or

```
SQL> insert all
  2    into mytable (mynew_col) values (1)
  3    into mytable (mynew_col) values (2)
  4    into mytable (mynew_col) values (3)
  5  select * from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]** Ah, you turned the question upside down. If you want to add a new column and limit number of valid values, then:

```
SQL> alter table mytable add newcol number;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table mytable add constraint
  2    ch_col check (newcol between 1 and 10);

Table altered.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> update mytable set newcol = 0;
update mytable set newcol = 0
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_COL) violated


SQL> update mytable set newcol = 11;
update mytable set newcol = 11
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_COL) violated


SQL> update mytable set newcol = 2;

16 rows updated.

SQL>
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong. I am trying to add a column and the values will be only 1 to 10. so I think I should use ALTER TABLE. I updated question, could you look at again please?

Comment: I edited the answer and added more info; have a look.

Comment: what is ch_col? btw and thank you for your answer. you helped a lot

Comment: You're welcome. CH_COL is name of the check constraint; that's how I named it, you can use any other name, if you want. But, I prefer PK_ for primary keys, FK_ for foreign keys, CH_ for check constraints so that I know - at the first glance - what they are.